# Is there any way to recover from an over-written android system recovery, or what else might cause a Pixel XL not to enter fastboot from recovery?

Tags: fastboot, boot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

This is an attempt to sideload an update to a Google Pixel XL stuck in a boot loop.
Following [this answer](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUsj_aeRj6Ak9M/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fphone-by-google%2Fj_aeRj6Ak9M) from the official Google forums, I tried [this procedure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6x7k-VkpUJMlZ1aEliVnhMOHM/view) as linked in the chosen answer. Unfortunately at step 9 it states:

```
9. You will see the Google logo for a few seconds followed by a green android on his back with “No command” underneath. Press and hold Power, then tap Volume Up once, then release Power.
   NOTE: If your device starts rebooting at this point, your only recourse is to contact your place of purchase about a warranty replacement or repair.
```

Unfortunately, sure enough - the device starts rebooting. This Pixel was bought by the previous owner from Verizon and I'd wager ten of them that they want nothing to do with repairing the phone, and would happily sell the user a replacement.
I don't understand what state the `android on his back` visual indicates, but I believe that the subsequent state would be the android system recovery. If the system is failing to enter that state and instead continuing to boot, it seems to indicate that a symlink or other direction or storage block has been over written. Is that true? And if so, is there any other way to enter android system recovery and continue to step 10 of the above-mentioned instructions?

For context: the user had started noticing battery/reboot/bootloop issues a few days before the device finally rebooted on its own and failed to completely start.
In trying to start the device normally, *occasionally* the boot loop will get far enough to spin the dots and display the "G" and `powered by android` at the bottom of the screen. It essentially always reboots after that to the `Google` splash that appears during initial boot-up.

For insanity's sake: Is there a way to JTAG into this thing?

#### Edit to add debugging info

```
user@host:~$ fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability
...
(bootloader)    get_unlock_ability: 0
OKAY [  0.052s]
finished. total time: 0.052s
user@host:~$
```

Comment: headline is wrong. repeat step 4-6 and post output of `fastboot flashing get_unlock_ability` if locked flash stock ROM and unlock bootloader https://www.xda-developers.com/unlock-bootloader-verizon-google-pixel-xl

Comment: @alecxs; Updated question to include requested information.... (reading your linked page now...)

Comment: @alecxs; after reading the linked page, I believe that that could be part of the issue (locked bootloader), but since the device won't boot, can I still unlock the bootloader?

Comment: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/2826033

Comment: @alecxs I found that thread - if that's the case, the expectations are pretty grim. Thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: sorry, no hope.. the xml files are not a big problem, we could write from scratch (just to flash twrp) but we need google signed firehose programmer for pixel xl https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3574278

Comment: @alecxs I did think about trying a "hail Mary" bash loop listening for a certain adb response during boot ... Which command should I have it try, and at what internal? (Interval shorter than one second?)

Comment: the adb server needs more than one second to even start up, it doesn't matter. command is `adb logcat` but it requires previously enabled and authorized usb-debugging (which is not the case after factory reset)

Comment: Well, there hasn't been a factory reset since this problem started; all the user's data is still on the device. It sounds like: _if_ the device will ever boot, the number one thing to do is USB-debugging? Or to try that unlock you linked? I've been hoping there is a slim chance it will fully boot, and I can do a command or two before it boot loops, with that command(s) unlocking something I need to use to side-load.

Comment: even with usb-debugging you can't do much, maybe uninstall some apps to free up space (sometimes the reason is low space). but yes, i have always enabled on my device. it is helpful in case screen is broken. but oem unlock is the most important (if you don't care about user data)

Comment: I'm considering running the following command while I let the device try to boot for a little while: `while [[ 1 -gt 0 ]]; do adb devices |tee -a /tmp/hailmary.txt; sleep 1; done`

Comment: Also, a device called the "octoplus" seems to be able to unlock some phones to varying degrees; there is some add-on device that adds the ability to manipulate the Pixel XL; that's also a consideration, since breaking it further than completely broken doesn't really leave me that worse off...

Comment: doesn't support google, not even MSM8996 there is no firehose programmer for google pixel xl https://octoplusbox.com/products/products