# How do I copy damaged data partition from locked Google Pixel

Tags: data-recovery, google-pixel

I have a Google Pixel (sailfilsh) device that complains about damaged data partition upon boot. It only offers to reboot (the same thing happens again) or to wipe the data.

I have not previously unlocked the bootloader, so trying to boot TWRP fails. I can't unlock the bootloader at this point, because doing so would wipe the data partition.

I am able to boot to the recovery mode, but the options available there look useless on surface.

Considering that I know the encryption passcode (numeric), is there a way to dump to data partition via USB to a computer? How?

(I'm mainly interested in recovering photos that had not been backed up by the time the data partition got corrupted.)

Comment: you are screwed. you can neither repair device nor safe your data. believe it or not, there is no official way to flash ROM with locked bootloader because google rely on fastboot. buy new phone that is googles philosophy

Comment: [Xiaomi Mi 5](https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=8346&idPhone2=6948) looks similar specifications. i don't believe it (because it should be OEM signed) but if you are really lucky the [prog_ufs_firehose_8996_ddr.elf](https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1) works for your device https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221452