# Recover files from android that wont turn on

Tags: data-recovery, google-pixel

I have an og Pixel XL, a couple years ago it died on me and went into a boot loop where it shows the white screen with a Google logo and then it shuts off and turns black, and it repeats. It will continue to try to turn itself on forever, fail, turn off and try turning itself on again until the battery dies.

The only thing that works to stop the cycle is holding volume down to open the bootloader screen, from here I have the following options:

- Recovery Mode      >>> Choosing this gets back into the boot loop I described
- Restart Bootloader >>> It restarts the bootloader...
- Power off          >>> Choosing this also gets back into the boot loop I described
- Barcodes           >>> Shows me the barcodes of the phones info
- Start              >>> Choosing this also gets back into the boot loop I described

I already bought a new phone to replace this one so I don't care so much about getting it working again, I assume this is some sort of hard ware failure. What I would like to know is if there's anything i can do to get files off of it? I have a lot of old photos and songs I'm hoping to copy off its storage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221452 sorry to say but there is no hope: you really should unlock bootloader on google devices. many people facing issues when OTA fails. if device is bricked with locked bootloader, google doesn't offer any method to flash stock rom. in such case you are lost

Comment: one thing you can try. install [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and [drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb). change slot a/b from *cmd.exe* with `fastboot --set-active=a` (b) and keep holding Volume Down while `fastboot reboot` maybe one of the slots let you boot into recovery, there you can wipe cache and try to boot